# How to evaluate $\lim_{|z|\to \infty} \dfrac{e^{-z^2}}{z}, z \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

I want to evaluate the following expression: $$\lim_{|z|\to \infty} \frac{e^{-z^2}}{z},  z \in \mathbb{C}.$$

It would appear that the answer is $0$, but how do you prove that rigorously?

Comment: The limit doesn't exist. $\infty$ is an essential singularity. Look for example at a) real $z$, b) purely imaginary $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit does not exist. To elaborate Daniel's comment, we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{xe^{x^2}}=0,\quad x\in\mathbb{R};
$$
but
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{-(ix)^2}}{ix}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{x^2}}{ix}\neq 0,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$